# testcontainers-node cannot start ruyk on GitlabCI

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, testcontainers

I have a trouble with running e2e tests via jest with using testcontainers-node on gitlab ci.

```yaml
default:
  image: personal-registy/node:14-alpine3.12

services:
  - name: personal-registy/docker:19.03-dind
    alias: docker-dind
    entrypoint: ['dockerd']
    command: ['--host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375']

variables:
  IMAGE: $REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker-dind:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  RYUK_CONTAINER_IMAGE: personal-regist/ruyk:0.3.2

stages:
  - Prepare
  - Tests

modules:
  stage: Prepare
  script:
    - npm ci --no-audit
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    expire_in: 1 hour

test-e2e:
  stage: Tests
  before_script:
    - mkdir $HOME/.docker
    - echo $DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG > $HOME/.docker/config.json
  after_script:
    - rm -rf $home/.docker
  dependencies:
    - modules
  script:
    - npm run test:e2e
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day
```

First step has no problem with building and preparing typescript code for test. But on running CI via npm command I got next stacktrace in log message:

```
Error: (HTTP code 409) container stopped/paused - Container d26dbb007bd42c3eb129e83db6253f3056fcc37294c84c4f00d13637bd451d6b is not running 
    at /builds/raif-capital/rcap-core-services/rc-operation-core/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:315:17
    at getCause (/builds/raif-capital/rcap-core-services/rc-operation-core/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:345:7)
    at Modem.buildPayload (/builds/raif-capital/rcap-core-services/rc-operation-core/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:314:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/builds/raif-capital/rcap-core-services/rc-operation-core/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:286:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  reason: 'container stopped/paused',
  statusCode: 409,
  json: {
    message: 'Container d26dbb007bd42c3eb129e83db6253f3056fcc37294c84c4f00d13637bd451d6b is not running'
  }
}
```

If I start test on local machine via npm I have no problem with running tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

Ryuk couldn't start because of problems with accessing to Docker socket.
I just disabled Ryuk on CI via env:

```yaml
variables:
   TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED: 'true'
```

After this my tests was completed successfully.